# Is IDL able to add / subtract from date?

Tags: idl-programming-language

As you can see the question above, I was wondering if IDL is able to add or subtract days / months / years to a given date.

**For example:**

```
given_date = anytim('01-jan-2000')
print, given_date
```

> 1-Jan-2000 00:00:00.000

When I would add 2 weeks to the **given_date**, then this date should appear:

> 15-Jan-2000 00:00:00.000

I was already looking for a solution for this problem, but I unfortunately couldn't find any solution.

**Note:**
I am using a normal calendar date, not the julian date.

Comment: Why not just convert to/from Julian so you can reliably add/subtract days? Take a look at JULDAY and CALDAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you only concerned with dates after 1582? Is accuracy to the second important?

The `ANYTIM` routine is not part of the IDL distribution. Possibly there are third party routines to handle time increments, but I don't know of any builtin to the IDL library.

By default, which you are using, `ANYTIM` returns seconds from Jan 1, 1979. So to add/subtract some number of days, weeks, or years, you could calculate the number of seconds in the time interval. Of course, this does not take into account leap seconds/years (but leap years are fairly easy to take into account, leap seconds requires a database of when they were added). And adding months is going to require determining which month so to determine the number of days in it.

Answer (score 1):

IDL can convert to and from Julian dates using [JULDAY](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/julday.html) and [CALDAT](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CALDAT.html).

You may also read and write Julian dates (which are doubles or long integers) to and from strings using the `format` keyword to [PRINT](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/PRINT.html), [STRING](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/STRING.html), and [READS](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/READS.html).

You'll want to use the [`(C())` calendar date format code](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/format_codes_fortran.html#files_2839720996_2823814).

```
format='(c(cdi0,"-",cMoa,"-"cyi04," ",cHi02,":",cmi02,":",csf06.3))'

date = julday(1, 1, 2000)
print, date, format=format
; 1-Jan-2000 00:00:00.000

date = date + 14
print, date, format=format
; 15-Jan-2000 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution looks quite good, but there is one strange thing that happens, when the date is printing out. The result for me is not `1-Jan-2000 00:00:00.000`, but it prints this:                            `1-Jan-2000 12:00: 0.000`. So I tried to set also the time to 0 and this prints out: `1-Jan-2000 00:00: 0.000`. Does this have something to do with the format or something with **JULDAY**?

Comment: Whoops! I used `csf6.3`, when I should have used `csf06.3`.

Comment: Yes, from the `JULDAY` documentation: "The JULDAY function calculates the Julian Date (which begins at noon) for the specified date."